# stored procedure returning `ASCII \0` error but can't find what that is referring to

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am writing my first stored procedure as a trigger. I am doing this in a dev migration as we have two systems which don't speak to each other in dev, so I need to mock the data which would normally come from the other system.

My procedure is added as part of our dev migration script.

```
DELIMITER |;

CREATE TRIGGER `activity_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `activity`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE `activity` AS `a` JOIN `handle` AS `h` on `a.handle_id` = `h.handle_id` SET `path` = CONCAT(`h.handle`,'/',`a.activity_handle`) WHERE `a.path` IS NULL;
END;
|
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: `\`a.handle_id\`` should be `\`a\`.\`handle_id\``

Comment: Or just leave out the backticks, they're not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect the logic to be:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER activity_insert BEFORE INSERT ON activity
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.path IS NULL THEN
        SET new.path = (SELECT CONCAT(h.handle, '/', new.activity_handle) 
                        FROM handle h
                        WHERE new.handle_id = h.handle_id 
                       );
    END IF;
END;$$

DELIMITER;
```

There are numerous problem with your code:

- You don't update the table being modified using `update`.
- You want a "before" triggers, not an "after trigger".
- Don't use `|` for the the delimited.  It is a valid MySQL operator.
- You have over-used the backtick, including putting the table alias in with the column alias.
- This assumes that `handle.handle_id` is unique.  This seems like a reasonable assumption based on the names, but you can add `limit 1` to guarantee no more than one row is returned.

Comment: the query of `handle` may potentially return more than one row (we don't see an indication of a unique constraint.. I'd add an `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1` to make the return more deterministic. otherwise +10.

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . That is a good point, but it seems reasonable to assume that `handle_id` is unique in a table called `handle_id`.

Comment: In that case (`handle_id` is unique in `handle`), adding the `ORDER BY` and the `LIMIT 1` wouldn't hurt anything. And it's the same pattern we use in the more general case, where we don't have (assumption of) uniqueness.

Comment: Wow! This is the best. I thought I was misusing the back tick. And was really struggling through the documentation of `DELIMITER` and when/how to use that. Nice catch on the `handle` as well. It is unique, but amazing what you guys where able to find.

Comment: @pedalpete a lot of people are confused by `DELIMITER`.  It is a client-side directive, not sent to the server, used so that the client doesn't see `;` and prematurely send only a portion of your compound statement to the server.  Using `DELIMITER |;` probably sets the client to expect exactly `|;` after the final `END` (which also does not technically need a `;` after it, before the delimiter).